# Considering performance what is the best way to DI (services) in Angular?

Tags: angular

Option 1: Using constructor to pass each and every service

```ts
constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA, public serviceB: ServiceB) {}
```

Option 2: Using `Injector` to initialize services.

```ts
private serviceA;
public serviceB;
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  this.serviceA = this.injector.get(ServiceA);
  this.serviceB = this.injector.get(ServiceB);
}
```

I am developing an angular library which can extend component and services. What do you think as a best way to implement such a case.

Comment: If you are using the `Component` decorator, I think DI is better. Since `Component` is a decorator in Angular, I think it is good practice to go with the same techniques as used in Angular. However if you use general classes, I would use option 1. The reason is because you probably want to use a class inside another component, so the component can inject a service, and then pass it to the constructor of the class.

Comment: @John considering the ease of coding, I prefer Option 2, since It only takes `Injector` to pass to the super when extending component. But performance is always comes in first. So I'm thinking which way should I go on. Because both ways we can pass to the constructor but option 2 is much easier. What I do not know is the performance wise comparison of these ways.

Comment: @AnuradhaMudalige could you point to any documentation from where you read `performance is always comes in first.`

Comment: @PardeepJain In my application performance is weighted more. That's why I stated performance is always comes first (in my context)

Comment: i dont think there is a big difference in performance, but option1 is definitely the better practice